# Not able to see first two characters in the file

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-go

Vim details:

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jun  5 2020 21:30:37)
macOS version
```

Here you can see that `package v1` word in the starting of the file is not visible properly.
This happens only with `.go` file, vimrc file as below,

```
syntax on

colo gruvbox

" Flash screen instead of beep sound
set visualbell

" Change how vim represents characters on the screen
set encoding=utf-8

" Set the encoding of files written
set fileencoding=utf-8

" Show tabs set 0 if donot want tabs
set showtabline=2

autocmd Filetype python setlocal expandtab tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4
autocmd Filetype go setlocal tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4
" ts - show existing tab with 4 spaces width
" sw - when indenting with '>', use 4 spaces width
" sts - control <tab> and <bs> keys to match tabstop

" Control all other files
set shiftwidth=4

set undofile " Maintain undo history between sessions
set undodir=~/.vim/undodir

" Hardcore mode, disable arrow keys.
noremap <Up> <NOP>
noremap <Down> <NOP>
noremap <Left> <NOP>
noremap <Right> <NOP>

filetype plugin indent on
set backspace=indent,eol,start

" go-vim plugin specific commands
" Also run `goimports` on your current file on every save
" Might be be slow on large codebases, if so, just comment it out
let g:go_fmt_command = "goimports"

" Status line types/signatures.
let g:go_auto_type_info = 1

au filetype go inoremap <buffer> . .<C-x><C-o>

" If you want to disable gofmt on save
" let g:go_fmt_autosave = 0
"

" NERDTree plugin specific commands
":nnoremap <C-g> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
"autocmd vimenter * NERDTree
"let NERDTreeMapOpenInTab='<ENTER>'


" air-line plugin specific commands
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
let g:airline_theme='angr'
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1

if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
    let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif

" unicode symbols
let g:airline_symbols.whitespace = 'Ξ'
let g:airline_symbols.branch = ''
let g:airline_symbols.readonly = ''
```

[image]

When I use visual mode on the `package v1`

[image]

Comment: With the cursor on either missing character, what do you get when you press `ga`?

Comment: I get `<p>  112,  Hex 70,  Octal 160`

Comment: With the cursor on the `p` or the `a`, do `:echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')`. It should give you the name of a highlight group (`goDirective`, for example) which you can then use like this: `:verbose hi goDirective` to see how it is supposed to be rendered. Can you report both findings? Also, when you enter insert mode, do you see those two characters?

Comment: ['goPackage'] & `::verbose hi goPackage
goPackage      xxx links to Statement
        Last set from ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/vim-go/syntax/go.vim line 19`

Comment: No I can't see them in Insert mode as well but after visual mode i can see them

Comment: OK, I got the problem when I turned on either `set showtabline=2` or `let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1` I started to see this issue, if I disbale them then I can see `package v1` word properly, @romainl Any solution for this issue?

Comment: No, but it looks like the next step for you would be airline's issue tracker.